# Remove trailling slash from base url in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got a React project using `react-router-dom`. I implemented `Browserrouter there`.

All urls have to look like http://localhost:8080/build/index.html?path=qmrelsr3pk2nnubhmb6iobj6ynr3ahiehuqa4

my `basename` in the  BrowserRouter is `/build/index.html`

All links generated in the DOM have the correct structure. However if I click on one of the, it adds a trailling `/` behind the index.html. So I cannot refresh the page without a properly configured server.

How can I prevent the `/` from being added?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked into the `history.push` like so:

```js
history.pushState = ((f) => function pushState(){
  arguments[2] = arguments[2].replace('index.html/', 'index.html');
  const ret = f.apply(this, arguments);

  return ret;
})(history.pushState);
```

I'm sure this is not a best practice, but hey it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just do this:

```
<Redirect
    from='/:url*(/+)'
    to={window.location.pathname.slice(0, -1)}
/>
```

At the start of your `<Router>` or `<Switch>` component. It checks if there is a trailing slash and redirects to the page without the trailing slash.

I'm also not sure about best practice and respect the answer of @pgalle